# Mahapps slows down WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

Since I added Mahapps to my WPF application it slowed down dramatically: it takes 5 times longer than before to start up and while editing the XAML code, Visual Studio often waits for 10 seconds or more while I'm typing.
Is this normal or are there tweaks to speed it up?

I'm using C# 4.0 on Win7 64bit.

Comment: could you give us more information? some xaml code etc? do you use listboxes, comboboxes or listviews? maybe the virtualization is gone... for this it exists styles for it...

Comment: @punker76: The application has about 10,000 LOC, dozens of text boxes, list boxes, combo boxes and data grids. Once it is launched and the objects are constructed, performance is ok, and the data sources contain only a few items; so I don't think it's a virtualization issue.

Comment: Same problem, I just have a MahApp window with no control inside

Comment: Is there a reference to "Icons.xaml" in your DictionaryResources, in app.xaml ? It is known to be a pain

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and it also started when I included "Icons.xaml". Did anyone find a resolution to this? It's not a huge problem, because it's not slowing down the execution of the actual app, but it's a little annoying during development.

Answer (score 1):

Have same issue when I included the Icons.xaml file. But I deleted all content from that file and just put only those Icons/content which I required/needed for the project. For now its working fine..

Answer (score 0):

If your having problems with the XAML in the designer perhaps you can try reloading it:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> 
Navigate to the Processes tab.
Kill `XDesProc.exe`

This will reset the Designer, if that don't work try rebuilding the solution.
If you are using NuGet package to install you could try uninstalling and installing again.

You could also look at your performence tab. You wil find it under <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> aswell. [image: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>]

Look at your memory and processor to see if its constantly peeking while you are running Visual Studio.